# Bash egrep numbers not working in case

Tags: bash

I'm reading a number from a file using

```
x= egrep "(^[0-9][0-9])" temp1
```

but when I use these numbers in a case statement it always fails:

```
case $x in
[0-9])
  statements;;
[0-9][0-9]
  statements;;
esac
```

when I echo the number it looks fine, I'm not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Please provide an example of the contents of temp1

Comment: 22

the file was created by

echo $1 > temp

Answer (score 1):

The bourne / bash case-statement matches the entire string, while egrep (in your example) is matching only the leading characters.

In your example, you would change your case-statement to be:

```
case "$x" in
[0-9][0-9]*)
  statements;;
[0-9]*)
  statemtns;;
*)
  statements for unmatched....
esac
```

Note that I reversed the order, because the first match will take effect. Also, I quoted the $x because I am paranoid ;)  You can leave out the quotes on $x if it might have leading blanks you want to ignore.

- Greg

Answer (score 0):

The space after the equal sign and no process substitution makes `x` empty. This may be why your `case` isn't working.

You can use the `-o` option to `egrep` to make sure you get only the string you're interested in.

```
x=$(egrep -o "(^[0-9][0-9])" temp1)

case $x in
[0-9])
  statements;;
[0-9][0-9]
  statements;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you want to do, you can do it with awk

```
awk '/^[0-9][0-9]/'{
  #do something
}' temp1
```

or with bash

```
while read -r line
do
  case $line in 
    [0-9][0-9]* ) echo "do something ;;
    [0-9]* ) echo "do something";;
    * ) echo "do something";;
  esac
done <"temp1"
```